# Undefined token in Internet Explorer vs Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, loopbackjs, strongloop

Using the [Building the TopBlogger API with Loopback](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2015/07/09/building-the-topblogger-api-with-loopback/) as a foundation, I created a small remote method example in Loopback.io shown below:

```
  Answer.remoteMethod(
    'upvote',
    {
      http: {path: '/:id/upvote', verb: 'put'},
      accepts: {arg: 'id', type: 'number', required: true, http: { source: 'path' }},
      returns: {arg: 'votes', type: 'number'},
      description: 'Up votes the answer'
    }
  );



 Answer.upvote = function (id, cb) {
      cb(null, 1)
  }
```

When I call the method then in the Loopback Explorer in Internet Explorer (Version 11), with the following URL

```
http://localhost:3000/api/Answers/17/upvote
```

I get the following error

```
    {
  "error": {
    "name": "SyntaxError",
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Unexpected token u",
    "body": "undefined",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "stack": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u\n    at Object.parse (native)\n    at parse (C:\\devel\\server\\node_modules\\body-parser\\lib\\types\\json.js:88:17)\n
```

The line of code that it is actually complaining about is in json.js

```
return JSON.parse(body, reviver)
```

But when I go to this URL in Chrome (Version 44.0.2403.125 dev-m) ... it works fine.

Is there some setting or something that I need to do in order for this to work in IE?

Comment: Using the StrongLoop API Explorer the above doesn't work in IE, but it *does* work in chrome. I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: Good practice : restart your server using debug strings (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Setting+debug+strings) `set DEBUG=strong-remoting:* && node .` and let us know the output. Also, please show us the json data you've attached to the request, it most likely comes from there

Comment: OK ... did that. (Thanks for pointing out debug strings!) What I see in the logs is what is returned from the statement. WRT the JSON data that is attached to the request ... there isn't any. It is just the URL above that is called.

Comment: Please post the complete log with strong-remoting and a screenshot of the explorer with the JSON data